# Cloudfront not forwarding request to origin for alias

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront, amazon-elb

Weird one here...

I have a CF distro forwarding to an ALB with a custom domain with an ACM cert. Accessing the distribution via the cloudfront.net url works fine, it also works fine via one of two aliases, however the 2nd alias throws a 502.

I have logging set up and when things are accessed via the second alias I get an error that says "CloudFront wasn't able to connect to the origin.", additionally CDN logs show an `OriginConnectError`. Looking at the ALB logs, requests never make it to the ALB when accessed via the second alias and looking at the server logs themselves the request don't hit servers behind the load balancer either.

So What I can see is that;

1. `cloudfront.net` -> `ALB` -> `Servers` [Good]
2. `Alias 1` -> `cloudfront.net` -> `ALB` -> `Servers` [Good]
3. `Alias 2` -> `cloudfront.net` ->X `ALB` [Bad]

I have tried destroying the distro and setting it back up again only to end up with the same result.

I have also tried using postman to send requests to the distro and these were the results;

- Send request to `cloudfront.net` url with `Host` header of `Alias 1` -> All good
- Send request to `cloudfront.net` url with `Host` header of `Alias 2` -> 502
- Send request to `Alias 2` url with `Host` header of `Alias 1` -> All good

I have additionally tried making another alias which in this case would look like `Alias 2-2` and it works fine, so it seems like there's some sort of conflict happening internally at CF which is preventing requests with a `Host` header of `Alias 2`.

Anyone have any insight on what could be causing this behavior?

Comment: A few things to check: does the TLS certificate on your ALB include `Alias 2`? Is CF configured to forward the viewer Host header to your ALB using either a cache policy (if part of the cache key) or origin request policy?

Comment: No the ALB cert doesn't include `Alias 2`, but it also doesn't include `Alias 1`, `Alias 2-2` or `cloudfront.net`. Yes CF does forward the host header.  Note that the only host header that doesn't work in this scenario is `Alias 2`.